# <adlcp:map> in scorm 2004 4th edition

Tags: testing, scorm2004

We are building API for scorm 2004 4th edition , we start using the  the official Test Suite but in the DMI test we get the following error :

"ERROR: Attempted to access an objective with the id "tarID1" but "tarID1" was not found."

when i looked in the manifest xml file i found that those elements are defined as "adlcp:map" , where shall i save this tag ? what this tag represent ?

Comment: You need to go read, understand and implement the SCORM 2004 4th Edition Sequencing and Navigation specification as well. In SCORM 2004, you can't just implement one of the books in isolation, you need to implement the whole set to be conformant.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike , yes that's what I'm doing right now.

Comment: @ghadaalsubih 
 
I started working on the same project. I completed the CAM book. Here in this case, <adlcp:map targetID = “dataMap1” /> i didn't get what is this shared data? and where it is located? what is it actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you would want to know about any element in a manifest (assuming it doesn't utilize third-party extensions) can be found in the official SCORM documentation.

Download the documentation suite.  In the CAM book, look for section 3.4.1.19, titled "<map> Element".

Source:  [SCORM 2004 4th Edition Content Aggregation Model (CAM) Book](http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/2004%204th%20Edition/Documentation.aspx), available from adlnet.gov (download the documentation suite).

Comment: I started working on the same project.
I completed the CAM book.  
Here in this case, <adlcp:map targetID = “dataMap1” />
i didn't get what is this shared data? and where it is located? what is it actually?

Answer (score 0):

This is used for shared buckets, or data which can be accessed and set across courses/SCO's. For example, you might have a pretest and need that score/user answers in another SCO for providing feedback.

For those looking for more info on implementation:

Add this to your item (organisation > item) in the manifest:

```
<adlcp:data>
  <adlcp:map targetID="mybucketname" readSharedData="true" writeSharedData="true"/>
</adlcp:data>
```

JS part (Use your API calls in place of LMSGetValue and LMSSetValue)

```
var dataBucketsCount = LMSGetValue("adl.data._count");
dataBucketsCount = parseInt(dataBucketsCount);
for (var i=0; i < dataBucketsCount; i++){
        if (LMSGetValue("adl.data." + i + ".id") == "mybucketname"){
                //do your processing with the data
        }
}
```

You can google for RTE Handbook SCORM 2004 4th edition, to get details on the manifest elements. 
However this is a lovely way to save data from one course and get it in other, provided your LMS supports it. Also, the character limit is same as suspend data.